# Validation for date/times that overlap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, validation, date

In my rails app I have a model called `Booking`. Users can book by selecting a date and then selecting a time.

Currently, I have a validation that checks whether the date and time combination already exists, and if it does then it raises an error.

The problem I am having is that each booking lasts for a certain time period, say 4 hours. Obviously I cant have a user booking at 8.30am, and another one at 9am, although my validation currently allows that.

I want to be able to check:

- Is the date and time combination taken
- Is the new booking being made while a different booking is taking place.

**For example,**

A user books for 2016/12/20 at 8.30am. The booking lasts for 4 hours.

Another user tries to book for 2016/12/201 at 10am, but because the booking is in the range of 8.30am-12.30am (4 hours), then it doesn't get validated.

This is my validation method currently:

```
def booking_available
    errors.add(:date, "and time is not available") unless Booking.where("? = date AND ? = time", date, time).count == 0
end
```

This is another one I have tried, although it only checks for the end of the booking period:

```
def booking_available
    errors.add(:date, "and time is not available") unless Booking.where("? = date AND ? = time + interval ?", date, time, (bookingtime.to_i.to_s + 'h')).count == 0 
end
```

The `date` column corresponds to the date of the booking, `time` corresponds to the time and the `bookingtime` corresponds to the length/period of the booking.

How am I able to check whether the new booking is in the range of other bookings and their times?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to store a start date and an end date instead of a start date and a duration, i.e. `2016-12-20 08:30` and `2016-12-20 12:30`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work for you but you can try something like this:

```
errors.add(:date, "and time is not available") unless Booking.where("? = date AND time BETWEEN ? AND ?", date, time - 4.hours, time + 4.hours).count == 0
```

This will work if your `time` is a ruby `Time` class object.

Comment: Had to modify it a little bit, but yes, `BETWEEN` is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to convert date and field data to a datetime format:

```
#method to get datetime from date and time column
#given date format = '2016/12/20' , time format = '8.30am'
def datetime_value
  (date.to_s + " " + time.to_s.gsub('.',':')).to_datetime
end

def booking_available
  errors.add(:date, "and time is not available") unless Booking.where(datetime_value: datetime_value .. datetime_value + 4.hours).empty?
end
```